# Replace all lines that start with #WAV with one single line, notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have thousands of files which all have a single chunk of lines that start with `#WAV`. This chunk could come anywhere in the file but is always a "chunk"

```
#WAV 001.wav
#WAV "something"
#WAV 21021029910291029.ogg
```

These chunks could be 1000 lines long or just 3 like the example above

I need to replace the entire chunk (all the lines that start with #WAV) with one single line.

So the above would just become

```
EXAMPLE REPLACEMENT
```

Note that this needs to work for any size chunk and what could come after `#WAV` is unpredictable.

using `#WAV.*` as regex wont work because it will replace all occurances of that line and not the entire chunk.

using `#WAV(.*)#WAV` and trying to replace the capture group wont work because I cant be sure of the "end" of the capture group.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple Python script for this? I believe that your problem could be solved fairly quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RegEx:

```
(^#WAV.*[\r\n]+)+
```

This will match all lines starting with #WAV on a single selection.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```php
^#WAV\b.*(?:\R#WAV\b.*)*
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/7xGBNw/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #WAV                     '#WAV'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \R                       line ending 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #WAV                     '#WAV'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

Comment: Simple is always best, but this answer is very nice too

Comment: @RafaeldeBem This removes `#WAV`s even on the last line. It checks if it is not `#WAVE...`, too.

Comment: Wouldn't `(^#WAV .*[\r\n]+)+` (with a space) work as well?

Comment: No, no it wouldn't